# C# SciLexer.dll question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, reference, scilexer.dll

I am using ScintillaNET a wrapper of the Scintilla control. I've edited the a lexer a bit and would like to try and see if the changes work, but the problem is I don't know which SciLexer.dll file it's using on my computer. The one in the application's directory did not seem to make a difference.

So my question is basically, how do I know which SciLexer.dll file my application is using and how can I set it to use the one in the application's directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Visual Studio, check to see which DLL your project references:**

1. With your project/solution open, expand the "References" folder in the Solution Explorer, and locate the name of the `SciLexer.dll` you are currently referencing.
2. Double-click on the relevant assembly to display it in the Object Browser.
3. In the bottom-right pane of the Object Browser, you will see the full path on disk to the specific DLL that your project is referencing.

This is the DLL that you need to change/update. Or, you could remove the existing reference and add a new one to the DLL in the directory that you want your application to use.